# Why are there so many non-composable commands in (La)TeX?

Tags: programming

Basically every time I start to do something non-trivial and try to remove repetition, I run into problems with non-composability of commands. Why are there so many non-composable commands in (La)TeX?

I don't have a complete list ready, but my most recent run-in is with '\verb' which cannot be used in an argument to another command, although you can use the listings package or fancyvrb to lift some of the restrictions.

Comment: Well, short answer: LaTeX is a macro programming language, and macros are, in general, not easy, often impossible, to compose

Comment: Then, for simple macros with no problematic side-effects composition is straightforward, but the more complicated ones have complex side-effects that do not compose well, hence the per-macro incompatibilities. If you come up with a list of problematic macros, there is going to be probably a very different explanation for each item!

Comment: @Bordaigorl, so IIUC you are saying this is inherent to any macro language?

Comment: `\verb` (and verbatim and listings) are very special commands that disable all latex syntax, by design they can not be composed with other commands. So they are very bad example for the general nature of your question. Do you want to ask about `\verb` or do you want to ask about the general nature of nested macro calls? They are very different questions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, both problems seem to present the same to the user. My question is about whether these are design/implementation limitations or whether these problems are actually impossible to avoid with any design.

Comment: `\verb` is by its nature non composable as it is changing the parsing rules on the fly so for verb (and other verbatim environments such as listings) it is inherent in the nature of the command. I can not guess what other cases you have in mind, so would not want to comment.

Comment: Making a statement about all "macro" languages is difficult because of its generality. I think the informal point is: when you have macros, the meaning of their composition is very hard to capture concisely and will not be very intuitive. This is why David hesitates in giving an answer: it depends on what you mean for the composition to be meaningful